# CSS Reverse inline flow

Tags: html, css

So, I have a line of inline elements that adjusts based on the width of the window, like so for example:

```
[a][b][c][d][e] -- 1000px

[a][b][c]
[d][e]          -- 600px
```

This makes sense, and is what is expected of inline elements. However, I want to know if it's possible to make it do this:

```
[d][e]  
[a][b][c]
```

or even

```
[a][b]
[c][d][e]
```

The reason I want this is because I have content below the row of inline elements, and when it breaks into two rows, having the top row be wider than the bottom row looks really bad.
Thanks.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Hm4C/1/

Notes:
Window width, element width and number of elements are all dynamic.
It has to work in IE9+ and FF24+, if this isn't possible FF has priority.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net ) of what you have tried?

Comment: Flexbox would help, though it isn't widely supported. If you know your resolutions to break the line on, you can perhaps use media queries.

Comment: `writing-mode ` could be an hint too , it would do  [d][e] -line break [a][b][c]

Comment: Do A, B, C, D and E have fixed widths? Or at least some of them?

Comment: If i'm right, they are left floated elements with random different width in a flexible width container? Are you open for JQuery solution or pure css? Maybe an example code would help us to answer.

Comment: The elements do not have fixed widths. I'm open to either CSS or jquery.

Comment: @ChrisHardie, "Flexbox would help, though it isn't widely supported" actually [it's supported pretty well cross-browser so long as you don't need certain older browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

Comment: I assume there could be any number of elements, and any number of rows that they're broken into?

Comment: I updated my solution to reflect the unknown number of boxes / widths info.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a "breaker" container like this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="breaker">
        <div class="box">Box 1 Bigger</div>
        <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="breaker">
        <div class="box">Box 3 Random</div>
        <div class="box">Box 4</div>
        <div class="box">Box 5 Stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.breaker { display: inline-block; }
.box { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will break `[a][b][c][d][e]` into

```
[a][b]
[c][d][e]
```

Now, in order to account for a dynamic number of boxes and widths, you need to use Javascript. With jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
function betterBreak(container) {
    var boxes = $(container).children(),
        sum = 0, max = 0;
    boxes.map(function(x, box) { max += $(box).outerWidth(); });
    boxes.each(function(x, box) {  
        sum += $(box).outerWidth();
        if(sum > max/2) {
            var breakerBig = $('<div class="breaker"></div>'),
                breakerSmall = $('<div class="breaker"></div>');
            boxes.slice(x).appendTo(breakerBig);
            boxes.slice(0,x).appendTo(breakerSmall);
            $(container).append(breakerSmall).append(breakerBig);
           return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Calling `betterBreak('#container')` on a Container element that has an unknown number of child element "boxes" will dynamically wrap the children in 2 `breaker` divs that split the line into the desired layout when going to 2 rows.

Adjusted Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pyU67/8/

Comment: I don't know how many elements are going to be in each row though. The width of the elements, the number of elements, and the width of the window are all dynamic. Thanks though.

Comment: So you have a random number of "boxes", each with a random width and you want the line to break in a way that has fewer / smaller boxes on the first line and bigger / more boxes on the second?

Comment: @Surgery You should add the desired random factor to your question, for the current state of your question this is a correct answer.

Comment: Random factor is now accounted for, however this solution is limited to 2 rows only, after that it breaks in the default way. And you need jQuery to use it. :)

Comment: Using sub containers is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You could use writing-mode as i commented , but for younger browser, Firefox seems out :http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/DCqLb/

```
body {
  counter-reset: boxe;/* demo purpose */
/* reverse flow from bottom to top */
  writing-mode:lr-bt;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
  -moz-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;/* fails */
  -o-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
  writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
}
/* demo purpsose */
b {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:3em;
  width:8em;
  text-align:center;
  background:lime;
  border-radius:1em;
  margin:1em;
}
b:before {  
  counter-increment:boxe;
  content:counter(boxe) ' ';
}
```

HTML use in body

```
<b> inline-box </b>
<b> inline-box </b> <!-- and so many more -->
```

**From your fiddle** , it does : http://jsfiddle.net/6Hm4C/3/ or just the spans http://jsfiddle.net/6Hm4C/4/

To test in IE, Safari, Opera, Chrome, and fails in FF :(

Comment: That does exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately it has to work in FF. I'll add that to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know about the `writing-mode` property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a divider like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
</div>
```

and use media screen:

```
.divider { display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .divider {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/24Jy9/1/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

> I'm open to either CSS or jquery. –  @Surgery

**Answer using Javascript / jQuery**

I have created a fiddle which creates a mirror HTML of what happens when the elements are shifted downwards.

---

**Here is an image example**:

> [image: Image example]

---

### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/wM7ZT/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <div class="inp">aaaa</div>
    <div class="inp">b</div>
    .
    .
</div>

<!-- Below part to generate mirror code of the above -->
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="second">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
var actual = $('#first');
var mirror = $('#second');

$('#wrap').css({'top':''+actual.offset().top+'px'});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var ele='div';
    var wrp = actual.height()+actual.offset().top;
    $('#first .inp').each(function(){
        var creEle = document.createElement(ele);
        creEle.className="inp";
        creEle.innerHTML = $(this).html();
        creEle.style.position = "absolute";
        var diff = wrp - ($(this).height()+$(this).offset().top);
        creEle.style.top = diff+"px";
        creEle.style.left = $(this).offset().left-actual.offset().left+"px";
        frag.appendChild(creEle);
    });
    mirror.html(frag);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,#first,#second{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#first{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#wrap{
    position:absolute;
}
#second{
    position:relative;
}
.inp{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I think making the elements absolutely positioned will cause all kinds of headaches... ;)

Comment: But its absolutely positioned within that container.Will not cause any problem as far as I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flex container](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=wrap-reverse&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=flex-end&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) with flex-wrap: wrap-reverse:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;  
  align-content: flex-end; // or flex-start
}
```